# Streams breaking tomcat load

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I am using maven to build a Spring 4 project. I have been compiling and running Java 8 for a while. But I hadn't used any streams until now. The project compiles and builds in maven, but when I add the lines that are using streams, Tomcat 8 throws a Spring error on startup. It's a spring configuration error, so something isn't liking the streams, because when I take them out, the error goes away.

It could also be hibernate. I am using Hibernate 4.2.4.Final. Is this compatible with Java 8?

My global JAVA_HOME points to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home

Here's the build portion of my pom:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
```

Comment: I would suggest upgrading the plugins to the most recent ones (2.5.1 and 2.2. are quite dated).

Comment: What jdk tomcat is using to start?

Comment: I think it's using jdk 8. That is my JAVA_HOME. Is there somewhere else to specify it? I even tried putting the java 8 location in setenv.sh.

Comment: I updated the plugins like so, but I still get the error. maven-compiler-plugin:3.1, maven-surefire-plugin: 2.17, maven-war-plugin: 2.4

Comment: Here's the error, it's on creating beans: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: